# How do I know if audio channel has been tampered?

Tags: audio, avi

I was given a AVI file which includes two streams: video and audio.
The audio is encoded using PCM signed.

In a specific time interval, the audio is muted.
I try to understand whether the audio was intentionally muted using a software or perhaps due to a loss of signal.

With `ffprobe` I found that in the silenced time interval, the data packets are all zero.

Here is a general example of that time interval *and its adjacent packets* (which include sound):

```
[PACKET]
codec_type=audio
... (trimmed for clarity)
size=1152
flags=K
data=
00000000: <arbitrary NON-zero data>
... (trimmed for clarity)
00000470: <arbitrary NON-zero data>
[/PACKET]

[PACKET]
codec_type=audio
... (trimmed for clarity)
size=2048
flags=K
data=
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
... Similar rows as above (data is zero), only difference is with the data offset
000007f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
[/PACKET]

<More packets with data equal to zero>

[PACKET]
codec_type=audio
... (trimmed for clarity)
size=2048
flags=K
data=
00000000: <arbitrary NON-zero data>
... (trimmed for clarity)
00000470: <arbitrary NON-zero data>
[/PACKET]
```

The packets' size alternates between 1152 and 2048.

I assume that if the silence is due to loss of signal, then the zero bytes should have started **anywhere** in the first packet where silence starts, not necessarily in the start of the packet.

I also assume that an audio editor program would silence the audio by packets, meaning it will *not* try to nullify the data bytes in the middle of the packet, but it will try to nullify all the data bytes of the packet.

Did anyone experienced with it and can confirm / supply additional insight?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder where your assumptions come from. Especially the floating packet size indicates that the audio frame size is not aligned with the video frame size which indicates your assumption might be wrong. As you have PCM audio, the number of bytes for audio aligned with a video frame is always the same. You can set up some wrappers/packetizers to align audio packet size with video packet size. But that doesnt seem to be the case for you.

The following is very depending on your environment, but it might give you some ideas:

If the editing program is a typical video editor like Premiere Pro or FCP X and co., it will align audio and video frames internally and not allow the editor to only change parts of one frame. This means that if there is some intentional silence, it will exactly match a multiple of the duration of a single video frame.

In case of a "signal loss", i wonder why you actually have nullified audio packets instead of missing packets but i assume your signal receiver just creates them somehow.

Anyway, my suggestion is to count all the the received audio bytes and see if the silence start exactly matches a video frame start. E.g. if you have 48kHz mono and 25fps, the signal loss should match a multiple of 1920 (48000/25) if it does not, you might deal with a signal loss.

In the end there are many unkown variables here that are environment specific: what is the signal chain, where can packets get lost, what is receiving the stream and generating the fill up packets? What codecs and formats are you working with? Are you bound to work with ffprobe instead of e.g. ffmpeg and silence detection etc...